# Changing an array object's elements

Tags: javascript, json, dom, google-visualization

First of all [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faQea/2/). I want to dynamically change parameters of variable `data`. If you look at Firebug console you can look at the data array object. I have looked up much but i couldn't figure out the `data`.

In short i want to regenerate the data array object with `return_data` elements. The `return_data` object's elements are dynamic. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faQea/2/) it has 3 elements but it may different than 3. How can i dymanically change it?

Thanks in advance.

```
var return_data = [{"name":"mrzurafa","count":315,"pop":5,"impact":7.37},{"name":"mutcato","count":20,"pop":5,"impact":56},{"name":"s0lukciyerli","count":3488,"pop":5,"impact":25.65}];

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['name','impact','pop','temp','count'],
  ['beyinsiz',80.66,1.67,2,33739900],
  ['mutcato',79.84,1.36,4,81902307],
  ['s0lukciyerli',78.6,1.84,8,5523095],
  ['herbkubilenadam',81.55,2.96,10,748560000],
  ['mrzurafa',88.09,2.05,40,307007000]
]);
```

Comment: So you want to convert the JSON in return_data into seperate arrays for use in data?

Comment: @MatthewRiches Maybe it isn't neccessary. I just want to replace return_data  elements with data elements considering that length of the return_data is variable.

Comment: I think you can easily transform one array to another using loops. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/faQea/3/) Thanks to all for you helps.

```
        jsonObj = return_data;

        var Obje = [];
        Obje[0]=['name','impact','pop','temp','count'];
        for(var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++)
        {
            Obje[i+1]=[jsonObj[i]['name'],jsonObj[i]['impact'],jsonObj[i]['pop'],10*i,jsonObj[i]['count']];
        }
        console.log(Obje);

        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
            Obje
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this returns a new list of which is structured in precisely the same way as your return_data:

```
var return_data = [{"name":"mrzurafa","count":315,"pop":5,"impact":7.37},{"name":"mutcato","count":20,"pop":5,"impact":56},{"name":"s0lukciyerli","count":3488,"pop":5,"impact":25.65}];

var data = ([
  ['name','impact','pop','temp','count'],
  ['beyinsiz',80.66,1.67,2,33739900],
  ['mutcato',79.84,1.36,4,81902307],
  ['s0lukciyerli',78.6,1.84,8,5523095],
  ['herbkubilenadam',81.55,2.96,10,748560000],
  ['mrzurafa',88.09,2.05,40,307007000]
]);

//prepare object
var item = {}
for (j=0;j<data[0].length;j++) {
    item[data[0][j]] = "";
}

//prepare list of objecs
var objs = []

for (i=1;i< data.length;i++) {
    item['name'] = data[i][0];
    item['impact']=data[i][1];
    item['pop']=data[i][2];
    item['temp']=data[i][3];
    item['count']=data[i][4];
    objs.push(item)
}

console.log(objs)
```

Hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 1):

So, I looked through API and played with your fiddle a bit.
It's pretty straightforward search & replace to look through the data and update values from the supplied array.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Za7T/

```
function updateData(data, keycolumn) {
  var i, j;
  // mapping
  var map = {};
  var keyColumnIndex = -1;
  for (i = 0; i < TheData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    map[TheData.getColumnLabel(i)] = i;
    if (TheData.getColumnLabel(i) == keycolumn)
        keyColumnIndex = i;
  }
  // updating
  if (keyColumnIndex >= 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var record = data[i];
        if (record[keycolumn]) {
            var matchedRows = TheData.getFilteredRows([{column: keyColumnIndex, value: record[keycolumn]}]);
            for (j = 0; j < matchedRows.length; j++) {
                for (var key in record)
                    if (key != keycolumn) {
                        TheData.setValue(matchedRows[j], map[key], record[key]);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    TheChart.draw(TheData, TheOptions);
  }
}
```

Where `TheChart`, `TheData`, and `TheOptions` are just global vars to `chart`, `data`, and `options` vars from your fiddle.

I'm also pretty sure it's not very efficient on loops, but you can optimize the basic idea however you wish.